# how to refer to resources created with for_each in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, foreach, routes, terraform, nat

This is what I'm trying to do. I have 3 NAT gateways deployed into separate AZs. I am now trying to create 1 route table for my private subnets pointing to the NAT gateway. In terraform I have created the NAT Gateways using for_each. I am now trying to associate these NAT gateways with a private route table and getting an error because I created the NAT gateways using for_each. Essentially, I am trying to refer to resources created with for_each in a resource that I do not need to use "for_each." Below is the code and error message. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
resource "aws_route_table" "nat" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
    cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.main[each.key].id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.vpc_tags}_PrivRT"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "main" {
  for_each = aws_subnet.public
  vpc      = true

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "main" {
  for_each      = aws_subnet.public
  subnet_id     = each.value.id
  allocation_id = aws_eip.main[each.key].id
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  for_each                = var.pub_subnet
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.main.cidr_block, 8, each.value)
  availability_zone       = each.key
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags = {
    Name = "PubSub-${each.key}"
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
Error: Reference to "each" in context without for_each



on vpc.tf line 89, in resource "aws_route_table" "nat":
  89:     nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.main[each.key].id

The "each" object can be used only in "resource" blocks, and only when the
"for_each" argument is set.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are referencing `each.key` in the `nat_gateway_id`  property of the `"aws_route_table" "nat"` resource without a `for_each` anywhere in that resource or sub-block.

Add a for_each to that resource and that should do the trick:

Here is some sample code (untested):

```
resource "aws_route_table" "nat" {
  for_each = var.pub_subnet

  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
      cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
      nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.main[each.key].id
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. I think this is definitely in the right direction. However using a dynamic block is still giving me the same error. I'll update the question with my changes.

Comment: I updated the response to tweak it as i realized what i proposed wasn't going to work but I don't think it will address the issue in your update... can you confirm what version of terraform you are using?

Comment: Hey, I am running terraform 0.12.26. I had tried what you posted before and got the same error as in my update.

Comment: ok, I did some research and instead of "each", it should be "route" in the case of this dynamic block, so I updated again, hopefully this gets closer to the solution

Comment: Hey, I think it is getting closer. There is an error stating unsupported attribute. I'll update with the exact error.

Comment: That let's run terraform apply but during apply what happens is it says error creating route because there is already a route for "0.0.0.0/0". What is happening is the second time it loops it sees the route out to the internet and then errors out. The exact error is : Error: Error creating route: RouteAlreadyExists: The route identified by 0.0.0.0/0 already exists.

Comment: ah, that is true, instead of creating a single route table with multiple routes, we should create a route table for each AZ/subnet... so in the end, we just needed to add `for_each` to your route table resource.. see updates

Comment: Thank you very much!